# How to break promise chain in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm migrating my Mongoose code to use Promises to avoid The Pyramid of Doom.
I want to break the Promise's chain on a certain point, but I don't know how to do it.
Here's my code:

```
var data = {};

People.find({}).exec()
.then(function(people) {

    if (people.length == 0){
        // I want to break the chain here, but the console.log() gets executed
        res.send('No people');
        return;
    }

    data['people'] = people;

    return Events.find({
        'city': new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(cityID)
    }).lean().exec();

}).then(function(events) {
    console.log('here');
    data['events'] = events;

    res.send(data);
});
```

Comment: Break, as in stop it from running because there's an error condition?

Comment: Yeah, if there's no result on the first query, I don't want to proceed to the next query.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28803287/how-to-break-promise-chain/45339587#45339587 Use `return { then: function() {} };`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to reject or throw an error in the handler to "stop" a promise chain from running.

From the [Mongoose Docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#promise_Promise-reject), you would want to call the `#reject` method of the promise.

The handler you have for `reject` should examine the reason and "do the right thing" (like cause a 404 to be returned or an empty array if you're doing RESTful stuff)

If you don't have access to the promise (since you're in the handler already for example), just `throw new Error()`.

This will invoke the rejected handler you provided.

Comment: OK, but how can I call the reject method?