# how to break promise chain

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, promise, selenium-chromedriver

I a promise in such fashion,

```
function getMode(){
    var deferred = Promise.defer();

    checkIf('A')
    .then(function(bool){
        if(bool){
            deferred.resolve('A');
        }else{
            return checkIf('B');
        }
    }).then(function(bool){
        if(bool){
            deferred.resolve('B');
        }else{
            return checkIf('C');
        }
    }).then(function(bool){
        if(bool){
            deferred.resolve('C');
        }else{
            deferred.reject();
        }
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

`checkIf` returns a promise, and yes `checkIf` **cannot be modified**.

How do I break out of the chain at the first match? (any way other than explicitly throwing error?)

Comment: Have checked this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20714460/break-promise-chain-and-call-a-function-based-on-the-step-in-the-chain-where-it#answer-20715224

Comment: @Mario, yeah, checked that, but mine is not broken, I want to deliberately break out of promise chain...

Comment: one choice you have is http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/1vc7crhw/1/

Comment: or a shortened version - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/1vc7crhw/2/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-deferred-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/1vc7crhw/4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you don't want a chain here. In a synchronous fashion, you'd have written

```
function getMode(){
    if (checkIf('A')) {
        return 'A';
    } else {
        if (checkIf('B')) {
            return 'B';
        } else {
            if (checkIf('C')) {
                return 'C';
            } else {
                throw new Error();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this is how it should be translated to promises:

```
function getMode(){
    checkIf('A').then(function(bool) {
        if (bool)
            return 'A';
        return checkIf('B').then(function(bool) {
            if (bool)
                return 'B';
            return checkIf('C').then(function(bool) {
                if (bool)
                    return 'C';
                throw new Error();
            });
        });
    });
}
```

There is no `if else`-flattening in promises.

Comment: one of the auti-patterns: then includes then

Comment: @KenBerkeley: `then` includes `else` includes `then`. Please suggest how to flatten it? And no, `then` inside a `then` is absolutely not a promise antipattern. You just must not forget to `return` the promise (as always).

Comment: @Bergi, is this not a candidate for your classic `.catch()` chain?

Comment: @Roamer-1888: It could be solved by throwing and `catch`ing as well, but conditional catches are complicated. Nesting is much easier and keeps the spirit of if/else better.

Comment: @Bergi, agreed conditional catches would be horrible but a conditional *throw* at each stage, just like your innermost then handler, with unconditional outer catches would be really neat, and amenable to a generalised `array.reduce()` solution. I would post an answer if this wasn't over a year old.

Comment: @Roamer-1888: The problem is that you must make the `catch` conditional, otherwise it swallows all exceptions. See vilicvane's answer which does that with `BreakSignal`.

Comment: OK, point taken, but it's a matter of opinion; for me even with a safeguard against unforeseen throws, a catch chain is more comprehensible than nesting. Maybe I just like catch chains.

Comment: @Bergi I read on the comments above that you said: _`then` inside a `then` is absolutely not a promise antipattern_; but I have always read that _never nest then-ables, it's a promise antipattern, just return them to the chain_. So, why you said that first?

Comment: @robe007 I say [never nest thenables in a `new Promise` constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572), and never nest `then` calls **unnecessarily**. It's great when you can simply `return` a promise and chain another `then` on the outside, and you should do it if your code still works when flattened. But that's not always the case, like [when the inner callback wants to close over variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28250687/1048572) or when you want to run parts of your asynchronous code conditionally. Promises are so powerful because they still *allow* this monadic style.

Comment: @Bergi Ok, thanks for the explanation. I made an approach using `Promise.all` to _avoid_ the _nested then-ables_. Can you please, [check it out](https://jsfiddle.net/reav5oh2/) and tell what you think?

Comment: @robe007 Looks fine for concurrent execution, but the OP of this question wanted something different: the `checkIf()`s should be made sequentially, and `checkIf('B')` should only be called when the `A` one had failed.

Answer (score 14):

> Any way other than explicitly throwing error?

You may need to throw something, but it does not have to be an error.

Most promise implementations have method `catch` accepting the first argument as error type (but not all, and not ES6 promise), it would be helpful under this situation:

```
function BreakSignal() { }

getPromise()
    .then(function () {
        throw new BreakSignal();
    })
    .then(function () {
        // Something to skip.
    })
    .catch(BreakSignal, function () { })
    .then(function () {
        // Continue with other works.
    });
```

I add the ability to break in the recent implementation of my own promise library. And if you were using [ThenFail](https://github.com/vilic/thenfail) (as you would probably not), you can write something like this:

```
getPromise()
    .then(function () {
        Promise.break;
    })
    .then(function () {
        // Something to skip.
    })
    .enclose()
    .then(function () {
        // Continue with other works.
    });
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use
`return { then: function() {} };`

```
.then(function(bool){
    if(bool){
        deferred.resolve('A');
        return { then: function() {} }; // end/break the chain
    }else{
        return checkIf('B');
    }
})
```

The return statement returns a "then-able", only that the then method does nothing.
When returned from a function in then(), the then() will try to get the result from the thenable.
The then-able's "then" takes a callback but that will never be called in this case. So the "then()" returns, and the callback for the rest of the chain does not happen.

Comment: Thanks, this worked in my case whereas others didn't apply or didn't work!

Answer (score 3):

I would just use [coroutines/spawns](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#promisecoroutinegeneratorfunction-generatorfunction---function), this leads to *much* simpler code:

```
function* getMode(){
    if(yield checkIf('A'))
        return 'A';
    if(yield checkIf('B'))
        return 'B';
    if(yield checkIf('C'))
        return 'C';
    throw undefined; // don't actually throw or reject with non `Error`s in production
}
```

If you don't have generators then there's always traceur or 6to5.

Comment: Why are you throwing `null` o_0?

Comment: Can't wait for all major browsers to support generators.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum OP rejected with `undefined`.

Comment: @simonzack so `return Promise.reject()` or `throw undefined` if you must (both are bad :P) but why throw null?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Yeah it is bad but I tried to preserve OP's code. null doesn't make much sense, you're right, I've fixed it now.

Comment: I've made an edit as stack traces are oh-so-invaluable. Feel free to revert if you disagree.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a `firstSucceeding` function that would either return the value of the first succeeded operation or throw a `NonSucceedingError`.

I've used ES6 promises, but you can adapt the algorithm to support the promise interface of your choice.

```js
function checkIf(val) {
    console.log('checkIf called with', val);
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(resolve.bind(null, [val, val === 'B']), 0);
    });
}

var firstSucceeding = (function () {
    
    return function (alternatives, succeeded) {
        var failedPromise = Promise.reject(NoneSucceededError());  
        return (alternatives || []).reduce(function (promise, alternative) {
            return promise.then(function (result) {
                    if (succeeded(result)) return result;
                    else return alternative();
                }, alternative);
        }, failedPromise).then(function (result) {
            if (!succeeded(result)) throw NoneSucceededError();
            return result;
        });
     }
    
    function NoneSucceededError() {
        var error = new Error('None succeeded');
        error.name = 'NoneSucceededError';
        return error;
    }
})();

function getMode() {
    return firstSucceeding([
        checkIf.bind(null, 'A'),
        checkIf.bind(null, 'B'),
        checkIf.bind(null, 'C')
    ], function (result) {
        return result[1] === true;
    });
}

getMode().then(function (result) {
    console.log('res', result);
}, function (err) { console.log('err', err); });
```

Comment: @downvoter, Would you mind stating what's wrong with the approach?

Comment: Not downvoter - but it uses the deferred anti-pattern for no reason - it's a bit pointless to pass deferreds around and to use `Promise.defer()` here.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Could you expand on this a bit? How would you allow `getMode` to return a promise that will only be resolved once one of the many async alternatives meet the succeeding condition without creating an extra promise?

Comment: I'd use `then` chaining.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Yeah, I had that in mind initially, but was concerned about having to make additional useless function calls until the chain end was reached even if the first operation succeeded. A successful result will have to traverse the entire chain with that design. I guess that's not that of a big deal. Also, I think your implementation needs special care for the last promise's result, no? Anyway, I updated my answer, is that better?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Looks much better that way. Thanks for the insights and simplifications. I didn't capitalized `noneSucceededError` initially because I saw it as a factory method, but it's true that in JS, most native constructors are actually factories so it's better named `NoneSucceededError`.

Answer (score 0):

i like a lot of the answers posted so far that mitigate what the [q readme](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) calls the "pyramid of doom".  for the sake of discussion, i'll add the pattern that i plunked out before searching around to see what other people are doing.  i wrote a function like

```
var null_wrap = function (fn) {
  return function () {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; i += 1) {
      if (arguments[i] === null) {
        return null;
      }
    }
    return fn.apply(null, arguments);
  };
};
```

and i did something totally analogous to @vilicvane's answer, except rather than `throw new BreakSignal()`, i'd written `return null`, and wrapped all subsequent `.then` callbacks in `null_wrap` like

```
then(null_wrap(function (res) { /* do things */ }))
```

i think this is a good answer b/c it avoids lots of indentation and b/c the OP specifically asked for a solution that doesn't `throw`.  that said, i may go back and use something more like what @vilicvane did b/c some library's promises might return `null` to indicate something other than "break the chain", and that could be confusing.

this is more a call for more comments/answers than a "this is definitely the way to do it" answer.

Answer (score 0):

Probably coming late the party here, but I recently posted an answer using generators and the [`co`](https://github.com/tj/co) library that would answer this question (see solution 2):

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/43166487/1337392

The code would be something like:

```
const requestHandler = function*() {

        const survey = yield Survey.findOne({
            _id: "bananasId"
        });

        if (survey !== null) {
            console.log("use HTTP PUT instead!");
            return;
        }

        try {
            //saving empty object for demonstration purposes
            yield(new Survey({}).save());
            console.log("Saved Successfully !");
            return;
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.log(`Failed to save with error:  ${error}`);
            return;
        }

    };

    co(requestHandler)
        .then(() => {
            console.log("finished!");
        })
        .catch(console.log);
```

You would pretty much write synchronous code that would be in reality asynchronous !

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use libs like thisone:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-chain-break

```
    db.getData()
.then(pb((data) => {
    if (!data.someCheck()) {
        tellSomeone();

        // All other '.then' calls will be skiped
        return pb.BREAK;
    }
}))
.then(pb(() => {
}))
.then(pb(() => {
}))
.catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
});
```