# How to break from a simple JavaScript Promises chain?

Tags: javascript, mongoose, mean-stack

I have a very simple JavaScript chain, much simpler than the previous similar questions' code: [a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20714460/break-promise-chain-and-call-a-function-based-on-the-step-in-the-chain-where-it), [b](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28803287/how-to-break-promise-chain), [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29499582/how-to-properly-break-out-of-a-promise-chain). So I am wondering perhaps there might be a simpler answer as well.

Here is my promise chain, with [Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html).

```
var someValue = 314;

// 1st promise
var promiseStep1 = step1.find({}).exec(); 
promiseStep1.then(function(doc1){
  // do stuff with doc1

  if (doc1 == someValue){
     // HOW DO I BREAK OUT OF THE PROMISE CHAIN 
     // and not execute the 2nd and 3rd promises below?
  }

  // 2nd promise
  return step2.find({}).exec();
}).then(function(doc2){
  // do stuff with doc2

  // 3rd promise
  return step3.find({}).exec();
}).then(function(doc3){
  // do stuff with doc3

  // we're all done here
  // handles error for all the promises
}, function(err){
  return err;
});
```

How do I break out of the promise chain in the `if (doc1 == someValue)` condition so that the latter promises don't get executed?

Comment: Too bad Javascript doesn't have  "goto" ;)  One other interesting link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29478751/how-to-cancel-an-emcascript6-vanilla-javascript-promise-chain

Comment: You can break out of a promise chain by rejecting the promise.  So for example, `return Promise.reject(new Error('Too bad so sad'))`