# What is the good way to break from promise chain?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, break, chain

I am wondering how can I properly break promise chain in JS.

In this code, I am connecting to database at first, then I am checking if collection already has some data, if not add them. Don't pay attention to some actionhero.js code..it does not matter here.

The main question is: **Is it okay to break chain using throw null?**

```
mongoose.connect(api.config.mongo.connectionURL, {})
        .then(() => {
            return api.mongo.City.count();
        })
        .then(count => {
            if (count !== 0) {
                console.log(`Amout of cities is ${count}`);
                throw null; // break from chain method. Is it okay ?
            }
            return api.mongo.City.addCities(api.config.mongo.dataPath + '/cities.json');
        })
        .then(cities => {
            console.log("Cities has been added");
            console.log(cities);
            next();
        })
        .catch(err => {
            next(err);
        })
```

Many thanks!

Comment: No, you should always throw an `Error` instance. In particular, never do `thow null`, as that would call `next` without an `err`

Comment: You also call next() without an err in then callback. So what the problem ?

Comment: But it does suggest a success result, which doesn't seem to be the case? Even if that is the expected behaviour, it's totally misleading.

Comment: Why not `return [];` instead?

Comment: Because chain may contain more than one or two cases..if you return []; you should check that result is empty in every then case.

Comment: For your title question, see [How to properly break out of a promise chain?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29499582/1048572)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28803287/how-to-break-promise-chain/45339587#45339587 Use `return { then: function() {} };`

Answer (score 2):

Despite it may seem like a clever trick and will work as You expect, I would advise against throwing non-error objects.

It would be much more predictable for other developers that will maintain this code if You throw an actual Error and handle it explicitly.

```
Promise
  .resolve()
  .then(() => {
    throw new Error('Already in database');
  })
  .catch(err => {
    if (err.message === 'Already in database') {
      // do nothing
    } else {
      next(err);
    }
  });
```

Comment: Looks really ugly to check this via error message..though two approaches (my and you) very similar.