# How to escape from .then() without executing the next statement in Express Js Promise?

Tags: node.js, express, promise

By using `mysql2` with `promise`, I have the **controller.js** as below :

```
exports.company_add = (req, res) => {
    company_model.company_add(admin_email, admin_info).then((result) => { ... })
    .catch((err) => { ... })
}
```

And the **model.js** as below :

```
exports.company_add = (admin_email, admin_info) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        connectionPool.getConnection((connectionError, connection) => {
        if (connectionError) reject(connectionError);
        return connection.promise().query('SELECT * FROM admin WHERE admin_email = ?', [admin_email])
            .then(([rows, field]) => {
                if (rows.length) reject('Email exist');
                else return connection.promise().query('INSERT INTO companydb.admin SET ?', [admin_info])
            })
            .then((result) => {
                console.log('result')
                if (result[0].affectedRows === 1) resolve(result);
                else reject('INSERT FAIL');
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                reject(err);
            })
            .finally(() => {
                connection.release();
            })
    });
    });
};
```

I wonder how I escape from the `.then()` statement when the line `if (rows.length)` occurred, since there is no need to continue with the next `.then()` for this case if the email already exist in the database. Do I need to `throw` it and add a `.catch()` just before the next `.then()` executed?

Comment: Hmn, if so, how can I handle the `reject('Email exist')` correctly by using promise? I tried in my application and yes, it does receive the `reject()` value but the code continuously executed until the last `.then()`

Comment: Does it means that I only execute one query per promise and decide to proceed or not with the next query according to the result?

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One cannot really [break out of a `then` chain](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28803287/1048572) other than by nesting or throwing an exception. Yes, in this case you probably should `throw`, but you don't need to `.catch` it when you avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it) and just make it a chained promise:

```
exports.company_add = (admin_email, admin_info) => {
    return connectionPool.getConnection().then(connection => {
        return connection.promise().query('SELECT * FROM admin WHERE admin_email = ?', [admin_email])
        .then(([rows, field]) => {
            if (rows.length)
                throw new Error('Email exist');
            else
                return connection.promise().query('INSERT INTO companydb.admin SET ?', [admin_info])
        })
        .then((result) => {
            console.log('result')
            if (result[0].affectedRows !== 1)
                throw new Error('INSERT FAIL');
            return result;
        })
        .finally(() => {
            connection.release();
        })
    }, err => {
        console.error(err);
        throw new Error('CONNECTION FAIL');
    });
};
```

Comment: And consider using a [disposer pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28915678/3478010) .... particularly useful if the codebase has many interactions with the database.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for your information and I had modified my code along with the promises supported `getConnection()` and the result is shown here : [link](https://ibb.co/kMNLwfp) It works nicely but I do have some doubt about the `.catch()`. Should I put it inside my code? Since I already implemented the `throw new Error()` in it. But if I not using `.catch()`, how do I catch the error when `.getConnection()` failed? Not sure about the correctness of the code structure.

Comment: @KtheKelvin You can [use the second `.then(…, …)` parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24662289/1048572) for that (see edit). Or put the `catch` there and have it distinguish between the `INSERT FAIL` error thrown from inside the chain and other database errors. Or just drop the `catch` and simply let errors propagate.